# Reasonable search range for HoughCircles param2?

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I'm writing a script to auto-detect some circles on a set of photographs. I've probably read every question about HoughCircles on Stack and the recommended approach generally seems to be to brute force both the radius interval and the accumulator threshold (i.e. param2). The range for the radius loop can generally be estimated from other geometric properties of the image, but what is a good approach to limit the search range for param2 automatically?

If anyone has any other tips for optimizing this brute force approach I'd also appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about param 2. It an accumlated effect to get things right.

Let take the following example. With the input

[image]

we can get different feature map according to a different parameter in other function like canny or other segmenation output

This feature is only good for line. whatever you choose for param2 the left circle wont come out

[image]

Here is another setting, by have it here, you can have the circle detected at param2 = 110

[image]

[image]

You see there is no perfect or optimized search range for param2. But the way you approach the problem matters.

Comment: I understand that there is a relationship between multiple factors, so the segmentation method will affect param2. In my case I'm using Otsu's method to automatically set the thresholds for Canny, before passing to HoughCircles. Hence I use this same threshold as param1. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to relate, for example, the Canny threshold or the circumference search range with param2, in order to limit the search range intelligently. In your example, how did you arrive at the value 110?

Comment: if your segmentation can give perfect result like only circle. then it can be any value 
greater than 10 for parameter 2. Bro there is no way you can sum it up for all cases. then there is front median or gaussian blur. You also want the overall parmeter 2 for blur radius + 4 or 5 segmentation parameter? no way you can get direct correlation.  110 is based on my experience. you will learn it in time.

Comment: think it this way, if there is already a relationship to all input and all output. when why we need you to write this code in the first place? I can write a code to do all the case without ever need a human intervention right?

Comment: So assuming my segmentation is good, would it be a good strategy to iterate from param2=10 until HoughCircles returns None/null, and then choose the best circle among those? Or just abandon Hough and use deep learning if my goal is complete autonomy?

Comment: if you want a black box auto solution. deep learning should be your top choice.  If you are keen to have explainable data, hough circle is the way.   prameter 2 is how ez you want a circle to be found ( accumulator threshold for the circle centers at the detection stage) . The smaller the value, the lesser the point needed to be selected as circle.  The bigger the value, the more point needed when classifying as a circle